# How to programmatically Bind a DropDownList when the items and the SelectedValue come from separate DataTables

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, webforms

For example:

You have 2 DataTables, City and Country:

```
Country Table
    CountryID (Key)
    CountryName

City Table
    CityID (Key)
    CityName
    CityCountryID (FK to Country)
```

In the City editing page, you want to provide a Countries DropDownList so that, when the user picks a Country, the DropDownList changes the City's CityCountryID field.

```
CountriesDropDownList.DataSource = GetCountriesDataTable();
CountriesDropDownList.DataTextField = "CountryName";
CountriesDropDownList.DataValueField = "CountryID";

// How to do this?
CountriesDropDownList.SelectedValueDataSource = GetCitiesDataTable(); //error
CountriesDropDownList.SelectedValueField = "CityCountryID"; //error

CountriesDropDownList.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the `DropDownList` has `SelectedValueDataSource` or `SelectedValueField` properties. Instead, you can use the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event to bind the Cities list once the user has selected a country.

Sample Code:

ASPX

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="CountriesDropDownList" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CountriesDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="CitiesDropDownList" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Code-behind

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CountriesDropDownList.DataSource = GetCountriesDataTable();
        CountriesDropDownList.DataTextField = "CountryName";
        CountriesDropDownList.DataValueField = "CountryID";
        CountriesDropDownList.DataBind();        
    }
    protected void CountriesDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedCountry = CountriesDropDownList.SelectedValue;
        CitiesDropDownList.DataSource = GetCitiesDataTable(selectedCountry);
        CitiesDropDownList.DataTextField = "CityName";
        CitiesDropDownList.DataValueField = "CityID";
        CitiesDropDownList.DataBind();
    }
```